# Handling lots of req / sec in go or nodejs

Tags: mysql, go

I'm developing a web app that needs to handle bursts of very high loads, 
once per minute I get a burst of requests in very few seconds (~1M-3M/sec) and then for the rest of the minute I get nothing,

What's my best strategy to handle as many req /sec as possible at each front server, just sending a reply and storing the request in memory somehow to be processed in the background by the DB writer worker later ?

The aim is to do as less as possible during the burst, and write the requests to the DB ASAP after the burst.

Edit : the order of transactions in not important, 
we can lose some transactions but 99% need to be recorded
latency of getting all requests to the DB can be a few seconds after then last request has been received. Lets say not more than 15 seconds

Comment: Have you considered [`INSERT DELAYED`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-delayed.html)?

Comment: No, but I really want to avoid the roundtrip to the DB server at all, I want to handle the burst as best I can with as few FE servers. Later when the burst is over I will connect to the DB

Comment: Understood.  However I suggest that you may wish to benchmark whatever queueing mechanism you decide upon against *pooled* database connections over which you `INSERT DELAYED`.

Comment: There's a lot more to know about this workload before any useful opinions can be offered. Do the transactions need to be kept in order? What's the consequence of losing (or discarding) some transactions? What is the latency requirement -- how long a delay between receiving the transactions and posting them is allowed?

Comment: thank Ollie, added some details per your request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is kind of vague. But I'll take a stab at it.

**1) You need limits.** A simple implementation will open millions of connections to the DB, which will obviously perform badly. At the very least, each connection eats MB of RAM on the DB. Even with connection pooling, each 'thread' could take a lot of RAM to record it's (incoming) state.

If your app server had a limited number of processing threads, you can use HAProxy to "pick up the phone" and buffer the request in a queue for a few seconds until there is a free thread on your app server to handle the request.

In fact, you could just use a web server like nginx to take the request and say "200 OK". Then later, a simple app reads the web log and inserts into DB.  This will scale pretty well, although you probably want one thread reading the log and several threads inserting.

**2) If your language has coroutines, it may be better to handle the buffering yourself.** You should measure the overhead of relying on our language runtime for scheduling.

For example, if each HTTP request is 1K of headers + data, want to parse it and throw away everything but the one or two pieces of data that you actually need (i.e. the DB ID). If you rely on your language coroutines as an 'implicit' queue, it will have 1K buffers for each coroutine while they are being parsed. In some cases, it's more efficient/faster to have a finite number of workers, and manage the queue explicitly. When you have a million things to do, small overheads add up quickly, and the language runtime won't always be optimized for your app.

Also, Go will give you far better control over your memory than Node.js. (Structs are much smaller than objects. The 'overhead' for the Keys to your struct is a compile-time thing for Go, but a run-time thing for Node.js)

**3) How do you know it's working?** You want to be able to know exactly how you are doing. When you rely on the language co-routines, it's not easy to ask "how many threads of execution do I have and what's the oldest one?" If you make an explicit queue, those questions are much easier to ask. (Imagine a handful of workers putting stuff in the queue, and a handful of workers pulling stuff out. There is a little uncertainty around the edges, but the queue in the middle very explicitly captures your backlog. You can easily calculate things like "drain rate" and "max memory usage" which are very important to knowing how overloaded you are.)

My advice: Go with Go. Long term, Go will be a *much* better choice. The Go runtime is a bit immature right now, but every release is getting better. Node.js is probably slightly ahead in a few areas (maturity, size of community, libraries, etc.)

Comment: This is good advice. Because Go channels are blocking (although they can be buffered too), they offer a very different model from Nodejs. In Go, it is safe to block without guilt. This makes flow control easy to design; something which can be *very* hard on an asynchronous platform such as Nodejs. You can explicitly design-in how to handle too-many messages, e.g. by throwing some away when the system is overloaded.

Answer (score 2):

How about a channel with a buffer size equal to what the DB writer can handle in 15 seconds? When the request comes in, it is sent on the channel. If the channel is full, give some sort of "System Overloaded" error response.

Then the DB writer reads from the channel and writes to the database.